# XCode14 WatchOS Storyboard

Tags: watchos, xcode14

In Xcode14, when creating a new watchOS app - SwiftUI is the only option. Is there a simply way to create a "New Project" template with storyboard/interface controller + delegate as before?

Comment: I am getting this issue as well.